# Pythonic way or more comprehensible with less struggle?

Tags: python

I am trying to be more Pythonic and less C++. However the limit of all lines to a maximum of 79 characters creates everyday struggle. Here is one example:

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self):  # version 1
    return [] if self._state != Game.play else [index for index, square in enumerate(self._board) if square == TicTacToe.square_free]
```

It is 138 characters long and has to be broken. (1) In three lines:

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self):  # version 2
    return [] if self._state != Game.play else\
        [index for index, square in enumerate(self._board)
         if square == TicTacToe.square_free]
```

(2) Possible in two lines (i, s instead index, square). Still 80, not 79:

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self):  # version 3
    return [] if self._state != Game.play else\
        [i for i, s in enumerate(self._board) if s == TicTacToe.square_free]
```

(3) In the end, I decided to keep that version:

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self): # version 4 (C++)
    if self._state is not Game.play:
        return []
    list_of_moves = []
    for index, square in enumerate(self._board):
        if square == TicTacToe.square_free:
            list_of_moves.append(index)
    return list_of_moves
```

What do I do wrong? Any better way to write this piece of code?

Comment: What do you mean by "[the original version] has to be broken"? Why isn't it acceptable in this form?

Comment: It is not *more pythonic* if it looks bad. Pythons philosophy  is to keep it readable and simple. If regular `if` statement looks better that ternary `if else` - use regular `if`. **Simple is better than complex**.

Comment: You could extract the array generation `[index for index, square in enumerate(self._board) if square == TicTacToe.square_free]` to a separate method and call that.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: Limit all lines to a maximum of 79 characters. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length

Comment: also a small detail, but I'd name the function `possible_moves()` or `list_possible_moves()` since the current name makes me think that it's a variable.

Comment: Interesting. I used it as a verb, but I think you are right. I will rename it. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a style/taste question; when in doubt, use the [`black`](https://github.com/ambv/black) code formatter on your code; if it looks ugly after Black, split it into multiple statements.

I'd "split the difference" and take care of the special case first, then use a list comprehension.

```py
def list_of_possible_moves(self):
    if self._state is not Game.play:  # Not playing, no moves possible.
        return []
    return [
        index
        for index, square in enumerate(self._board)
        if square == TicTacToe.square_free
    ]
```

Comment: this is very nice, the `return []` also makes the function skip the rest if `self._state` is not `Game.play`

Comment: I got three answers. The rest two are similar to your answer. I will accept yours since it was the first, plus bonus: black code formatter :-) Thank you!

Comment: Tooting my own horn a little here – if you want to run Black without installing, check out my https://nicen.pw/ site :)

Answer (score 3):

First, you can expand your `if, else` one-liner:

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self):
    if self._state != Game.play:
        return []
    else:
        return [index for index, square in enumerate(self._board) if square == TicTacToe.square_free]
```

But it's still a bit longer.
A good way to break a comprehension is value - `for` - condition, as suggested by the [Google styleguide](https://github.com/google/styleguide/blob/gh-pages/pyguide.md#27-comprehensions--generator-expressions):

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self):
    if self._state != Game.play:
        return []
    else:
        return [
            index 
            for index, square in enumerate(self._board) 
            if square == TicTacToe.square_free
        ]
```

But if you don't want to expand it, you can rename `index` into `i`, which is perfectly valid in 1. a comprehension, and 2. with `enumerate`. You can rename `square` as well:

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self):
    if self._state != Game.play:
        return []
    else:
        return [i for i, sq in enumerate(self._board) if sq == TicTacToe.square_free]
```

Here it's 85 character long, so just a little too long, but this can help reduce your lines in general.

Comment: Thank you! Great answer!

Answer (score 3):

The long version is the most redeable one, you can use comprehensions pipeline anyway:

```
def list_of_possible_moves(self): # version 4 (C++)
    if self._state is not Game.play:
        return []
    non_squares_indexes = [
        i for i, x in enumerate(self._board) if x == TicTacToe.square_free
    ]
    return non_squares_indexes
```

Comment: sorry, what is the `3` in the `[list_of_moves.3(index)` in the last row of your example. Thanks !

Comment: @reportgunner, actually it was a typo that lead me to duplicate code

Comment: Thank you! Great answer! It looks like the version of 1 even you started from 4 :-)

Answer (score 3):

Thinking outside the box for a bit - consider whether the `self._state` check really belongs at this level of the code. If your class needs to check `self._state` in multiple places, that's a smell suggesting that you [replace the conditional logic with polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484849/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism-how-to-handle-when-your-type-changes). Now you have a separate class for the main gameplay state, which determines the possible moves via the comprehension; and other classes for other game states that just give you the empty list - assuming that you really need this to be part of the interface (consider whether you really need to be able to check the list of available moves when the game is not being played!).

Comment: You are right. Great observation! Actually, I don't need to check `self._state` after you noticed it. I only call `list_of_possible_moves` in the code when `self._state == Game.play`.Thank you!

Comment: Also gained 0.03 second in 10000 games :-)